# Is it possible to create an API endpoint in REST API if the resource is not an entity?

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, api-design, clean-architecture

I am developing an electronic salary diary application. On the backend, I have "entries" entities with "Date" properties.

Now I have a react application that takes all the entries, groups them by month, and then by day. And it seems to me that I do a lot of unnecessary work on the client, because I also have such entities as "payment", "deduction" I also select them, in general, overloaded components are obtained.

Question. How much will it be right if I make a "WorkingMonth" service on the backend, and collect all the information there and issue it through some API endpoint? After all, there is no such entity.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You can do whatever you want with the organization of your api's. There is no single source of truth for architecture and if it works for you then go for it. Personally I'm all for off loading as much as possible to the backend services.

Comment: I'm just trying to follow the right design approaches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, how things are stored in your persistence layer shouldn't be a concern in terms of API design. Your data model isn't your object model, your object model isn't your API model. And you're realizing this.

That's why your API code exists, not to simply map columns on a database (or properties of a document) to a JSON (or XML) structure, but to map the model that works well for your *code* into a model that works well for your API *client*.

It may make sense to normalize the data and store it in a relational database on the *server*, while the *client* wants a bunch of related data together in something that makes sense in a specific context.

One thing you may want to keep in mind, if you're just trying to avoid the HTTP requests because the client code does work well traversing relationships your API exposes (which may be different than tables in a database) you could consider embedding some resources instead of creating a new 'aggregate' resource. But that really depends on the context.

Also, there's absolutely nothing wrong with exposing the same data in multiple resources, if that makes sense for the client.

Answer (score 0):

> How much will it be right if I make a "WorkingMonth" service on the backend, and collect all the information there and issue it through some API endpoint?

From a REST perspective? It will be almost completely right -- there's only a vocabulary issue ([REST has "resources", not "endpoints"](https://twitter.com/fielding/status/1052976631374000128?lang=en)).

"Any information that can be named can be a resource" -- [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)

How you create the representation of a resource is an implementation detail, hidden behind the "uniform" resource interface.